# How do I improve performance for same table join? Somehow 1 index is not used

Tags: mysql

I have a table for start and end year for each subscription payment.

There are about 45,000 records.

```
CREATE TABLE `a_payment` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pay_id`),
  KEY `end_year` (`end_year`),
  KEY `start_year` (`start_year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I want to find the renewal count for the year that the subscription expires.

It reduces 45,000 records to 10 records, 1 for each year.

```
select  t1.end_year as year
        , 0 as total
        , count(t1.user_id) as renew
from    a_payment t1
    , a_payment t2
where   t1.user_id = t2.user_id
and t1.end_year = t2.start_year
group by t1.end_year
order by t1.end_year
```

It takes 2 min 58 seconds.

The "sending data" takes 178 seconds, 99.99962%.

DESCRIBE the select statement shows

1. select type simple, table t1, type all, key null, rows 39267, extra using where; using temporary; using filesort
2. select type simple, table t2, type ref, key start_year, row t1.end_year, rows 7557, using where

Why is it taking so long?  How come the end_year index is not used?  What do I need to change to make it faster?

Comment: Please use modern join syntax. The syntax you are using is from the 80s.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using any filtering condition so your query needs to read at least one of the table fully.

The query can benefit from the index:

```
create index ix1 on a_payment (end_year, user_id);
```

but most importantly from the index:

```
create index ix2 on a_payment (user_id, start_year);
```

Also, please use modern join syntax. You query can be rephrased as:

```
select  t1.end_year as year
        , 0 as total
        , count(t1.user_id) as renew
from    a_payment t1
join    a_payment t2 
     on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.end_year = t2.start_year
group by t1.end_year
order by t1.end_year
```

Comment: Adding the 2 keys work!  Adding 1 key for all 3 columns works too. 
key `user_start_end_year` (`user_id`,`start_year`,`end_year`)